# Esperar 3 segundos quando clicar em fechar o console

Tags: c#

Como posso fazer para que espere 3 segundos para fechar o console?

```
Thread.Sleep(3000)
```

Só não sei aplicar ao console. Podem me explicar?

Ele apertaria no botão X para fechar o console e esperava 3 segundos para fechar

Comment: Se tem mais código?

Comment: Não, creio eu que seja na parte de código padrão do console.

Comment: Como você que não é na parte do código? se a sua pergunta é sobre isso. Estranha colocação.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acho que é isso o que você quer...

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;

namespace ConsoleApp1
{
    class Program
    {
        // http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.setconsolectrlhandler
#region pinvoke
        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        static extern bool SetConsoleCtrlHandler(ConsoleCtrlDelegate HandlerRoutine, bool Add);

        // Delegate type to be used as the Handler Routine for SCCH
        delegate Boolean ConsoleCtrlDelegate(CtrlTypes CtrlType);

        // Enumerated type for the control messages sent to the handler routine
        enum CtrlTypes : uint
        {
            CTRL_C_EVENT = 0,
            CTRL_BREAK_EVENT,
            CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT,
            CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT = 5,
            CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT
        }
#endregion

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var consoleCtrl = new ConsoleCtrlDelegate(ConsoleCtrlCheck);
            GC.KeepAlive(consoleCtrl);

            SetConsoleCtrlHandler(consoleCtrl, true);

            while(true)
            {
                // tarefa longa, mantendo o console aberto ...
            }
        }

        private static bool ConsoleCtrlCheck(CtrlTypes ctrlType)
        {
            if (ctrlType == CtrlTypes.CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("3...");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("2...");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("1...");
                Thread.Sleep(1000);
                Console.WriteLine("Tchau!");
            }

            return true;
        }
    }
}
```